# How can i add a cloned git repository zip file to Azure devops?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a git repository on a bit bucket server and I am trying to move to azure devops, so i tried to import the contents of the repository from the one on my bit bucket server and discovered that there are some connection issues related to firewalls which will not be resolved. So therefore, I tried to download the git repository on a bit bucket server to my local computer.

Is there a stipulated process which now I can follow to add this zip file and create a repository out of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to import repo directly from zip file. But when you create a new repo on Azure DevOps you can find this section in repo details:

[image: Import repo]

So basiclly what you need is to extract repo on your local machine, got to this folder in your terminal and run these commands.